# Putting a ByteBuffer into a Bundle

Tags: java, android

I'm working with some code that I have no control over, and the ByteBuffer I'm working with gets passed to native method. I don't have access to the native code but it expects "buf" to be a ByteBuffer. Also note that the code doesn't really make any sense but there is a lot so I am distilling it down to the issue.

```
public class otherClass {
    public final void setParams(Bundle params) {
            final String key = params.keySet()[0];
        Object buf = params.get(key));
        nativeSet(key, buf);
    }

    private native final void nativeSet(key, buf);
}
```

Here is my code:

```
 public void myMethod(ByteBuffer myBuffer) {

        final Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
        myBundle.putByteBuffer("param", myBuffer);
        otherClass.setParams(runTimeParam);

}
```

The problem? There is no putByteBuffer method in Bundle. Seems kind of weird that there is a get() that returns an object, but no generic put().

But what seems weirder to me is that the native code wants a ByteBuffer. When it gets passed from Java layer, won't it have a bunch of metadata with it? Can code in the native layer predict the metadata and extract from the ByteBuffer?

Is there any way to reliably pass a ByteBuffer here? It can be a little hacky. I was thinking maybe I could figure out what the ByteBuffer object would be in bits, convert to integer, and use putInt(). Not sure how to go from ByteBuffer object to raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically this should work. Turn the byte buffer to a string and pass that into your bundle like this:

```
byte[] bytes = myBuffer.getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8" ));
String byteString = new String( bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );
myBundle.putString("param", byteString);
```

then reconstruct the bytebuffer from the string:

```
byte[] byteArray = byteString.getBytes();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArray.length + 8);
byteBuffer.put(byteArray);
```